# Assembly not jumping properly

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly

I am having a problem understanding why my cmp statements are not working correctly.

When I run this, I enter 0 in first and it goes to storeValue. I enter 0 in for the second value and it goes to the searchArray like it is supposed to.

I have breakpoints on my cmp and jump statements and a watch on AL so I don't understand why it's storing the first 0 when it should prompt for the search value at that point.

Thanks for looking.

```
.DATA
prompt1     BYTE    "Enter a value to put in array or 0 to search array.", 0
prompt2     BYTE    "Enter a value to search array for.",0                         
intArray    DWORD   ?
numElem     DWORD   0
SearchVal   DWORD   ?

resultNope  BYTE    "Not in array.",0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
            lea     ebx, intArray           ;get the address of array.
start:      input   prompt1, intArray, 50   ;read in integer
            atod    intArray                ;convert to int

            mov     al, [ebx]               ;move int to register
            cmp     al, 0                   ;if integer is positive - store it!
            jg      storeValue              ;JUMP!

            cmp     al, 0                   ;if 0 - time to search array!
            je      searchArray             ;JUMP!

storeValue: add     numElem, 1              ;Adds 1 to num of elements in array.
            mov     [ebx], al               ;moves number into array.
            add     ebx, 1                  ;increment to next array address.
            jmp     start                   ;get next number for array. JUMP!

searchArray:input   prompt2, searchVal, 50  ;What are we searching array for?
            atod    searchVal               ;convert to int
            lea     ebx, intArray           ;get address of array.
            mov     ecx, 1                  ;set loop counter to 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to show how `input` and `atod` work. Looking into my crystal ball, I guess that `input` expects a buffer to store the user input as text, and the argument `50` is presumably its size. Notice that you don't have such a buffer and you don't even have 50 bytes space. I also think that since `atod` apparently only takes 1 argument, which is the text buffer to convert, it presumably returns the value in `eax`. This is also reinforced by the fact that your `storeValue` writes from `al` which would make no sense otherwise.

Long story short:

1. allocate a buffer of the proper size for the text entered
2. pass this array to `atod`
3. do not clobber `al` after the call to `atod`

(Applies to the search part too.)

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning 80x86 asm and I assumed atod and input were standard syntax from how the book explained it. Looking into it more I found they are macros. Thanks though! I figured it out, I stupidly forgot to move the value after I called atod from EAX to [EBX] which solved my problem right up. Thanks!